# Target-typed object creation working in web project but not in class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I use:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
```

then it works in everything.

If I use target-typed object creation

```
StringBuilder myString = new();
```

It works fine in a web project but not in a class library project. Both are using .Net 4.7.2 and so, as far as I can see, should be restricted to C# 7.x [C# Versions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-versions/)

In the web project it just works, in the class library I get an error where the new is underlined in red and the following error message:

```
"Feature target-typed object creation is not available in C# 7.3 Please use language version 9 or higher"
```

So how on earth is the web project working if it requires C# 9 (was released with .Net 5.0) or higher?

**EDIT1**: When I go into Build > Advanced, the language version is disabled and says 'Automatically selected based on framework version' which is 4.7.2 and according to many sources should be C# 7 which doesn't support it. This applies to both the web project and the class library. There is a link titled' Why can't I choose my own version' which is this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

**EDIT2**: I meant to say that by default .Net 4.7.2 is restricted to C# 7.3 and it can be changed by altering `<LangVersion>` in the csproj file, but this hasn't been done for the working project it is still `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>`

**EDIT3**: The class library which wouldn't allow target-typed object creation actually had the C# version set as: `<LangVersion>7.3<LangVersion>`
By setting this to default as was always the case with the web project (which allowed target-typed object creation), so now the same questions stands but it is now for the class library to.

How are both projects using C# 9 code when they are both .Net 4.7.2 with a `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` which can be found to say that default means the latest version that the framework will support, but also on MS own site, that the default C# for .Net 4.7.2 is C# 7.3. Is there any documentation which says otherwise?

P.S. If I looked at the language version via 'build > advanced' it would only say 'Automatically selected based on framework version', I had to edit the csproj file with a text editor to see that one was default and one was C# 7.3.

Comment: You may have the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompiler nuget package installed in the web project but not the class library; therefore, allowing the web project to target later syntax versions of C#.

Comment: What language version is selected for web project? If you have newer SDK installed it will be used by default to compile project and if the feature you are trying to use has not required CLR changes compiler in theory can handle it.

Comment: @JoshMein Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompiler is not utilised.

Comment: @GuruStron I forgot to say earlier; when I go into Build > Advanced, the language version is disabled and says 'Automatically selected based on framework version' which is 4.7.2 and according to many sources should be C# 7 which doesn't support it.

Comment: .NET 4.7.2 is not restricted to c# 7 - you can install the nuget and set the language property in csproj

Comment: @YehorAndrosov Yes, I meant to say by default 4.7.2 is restricted to C# 7.3 and it can be changed by altering <LangVersion> in the csproj file, but this hasn't been done for the working project it is still <LangVersion>default</LangVersion>

Comment: @YehorAndrosov Forgot to say that the nuget (nor any other) package isn't installed in the solution, but see EDIT3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question of why is as follows:

"The default choice is the latest major version that is supported by the target framework. This, however, is not equivalent to setting the `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` property in the .csproj file."

Of course specifying default in LangVersion isn't the same as not specifying the LangVersion and it using the defaulty max supported framework version for .Net 4.7.2, i.e. C# 7.3.

Of course not!... Using `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` is the same as using `<LangVersion>latestMajor</LangVersion>` what the actual flip? Which basically means that "The compiler accepts syntax from the latest released major version of the compiler."

Which is why `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` in the csproj file of the web project was allowing C# 9.0 syntax.

If I removed this section (as I have now discovered is the case in some of the projects in the solution) then those projects would also allow C# 9.0!

See, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Now, which compiler am I using and what is the latest syntax version of C# that it supports?...